# Delete old map markers and load new ones in cluster manager

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, cluster-computing, markerclusterer

I have a google map, and what I'm trying to do is to refresh markers from firebase every 15 seconds using geoQuery, And that means I delete all the previous markers and add new ones by using this method :

```
private void downloadExtraPrinters(LatLng viewCenter, int viewRadius) {

    try {

        final GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(viewCenter.latitude,viewCenter.longitude), viewRadius);
        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {

                try{
                    MyItem myItem = new MyItem(location.latitude, location.longitude);
                    if (!items.contains(myItem)) {
                        items.add(myItem);
                    }

                }catch (ClassCastException e){

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {

                parseJsonToList();
            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }catch (NullPointerException e){

    }


}
```

parseJsonToList methode :

```
private void parseJsonToList() {


itemss = clusterManagerAlgorithm.getItems();
try {
    items.removeAll(itemss);
}catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    Log.d("itemsDoesn't exist"," : ");
}


mClusterManager.clearItems();      // I Think the problem is in this 3 lines of code.
mClusterManager.cluster();         // I also tried addItems(items) before clustering i still getting the same problem.
mClusterManager.addItems(items);

}
```

My problem is that every time I want to clean and reload data, all the markers disappear for 15 seconds until the next call of the parseJsonToList method all markers appears again after 15 seconds.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("timer","executed");
             if (viewCenter != null) {
                downloadExtraPrinters(viewCenter, viewRadius);
                Log.d("download","newData");
            }

        }
    }, 0, 15000);  // all data reloaded every 15s.
}
```

Here it is myItem class :

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {
private final LatLng mPosition;

public MyItem(double lat, double lng) {
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
}

@Override
public LatLng getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    MyItem item = (MyItem) o;
    return Objects.equals(mPosition, item.mPosition);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(mPosition);
}
}
```

What I want is to change markers immediately without been disappear for 15 seconds. I was struggling with this issue for 2 weeks please help!

Comment: Post the MyItem implemention of `equals` or note if it is not being overridden.

Comment: I already override equals and also hashCode in myItem.class -- Andy

Comment: Right - so if you are doing something like comparing lat/lngs in the equals then the problem is one pass you remove everything and then 15 seconds later they are added back, which is why I was hoping you could post the equals code.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the clusterManager is empty initially and the initial geoquery returns a single result A.

On entry to `parseJsonToList`, `items` has one entry in it (A) and this line:

```
itemss = clusterManagerAlgorithm.getItems();
```

returns an empty `Collection`.

Since `itemss` is empty then

```
items.removeAll(itemss);
```

has no effect and the rest of the code will add A to the map.

Now, 15 seconds later the same result is returned (A), this line

```
itemss = clusterManagerAlgorithm.getItems();
```

returns a collection with one item that is equivalent to A (by position (equals)) and now

```
items.removeAll(itemss);
```

will remove the current result (A) because it is also in `itemss` (again by `equals` using position).

So then when you add `items` in this line:

```
mClusterManager.addItems(items);
```

nothing is added because `items` is empty.

And so the pattern is most likely..

```
the marker appears
15 seconds later the marker disappears
15 seconds later the marker appears
```

I can't recommend a solution since I can't understand why the `clearItems` at the end - if you really want to do that then just get rid of the "remove" logic altogether.  And the documentation does recommend force cluster *after* the add.

Comment: Consider that there isn't clearItems what is the solution is this case Andy?

Comment: In that case, reverse the removal logic - remove the `items` from the `itemss` - but since there is no "removeAll" you'll have to loop over `items` and `removeItem`.  But this gets back to your `equals` - if they ever "move" then you'll never delete them - your logic only applies if they are added/deleted which may be the case.